# Prove $P[A^c \cap B^c] = P[A^c]P[B^c]$ without using independence

Tags: probability

If $P[A \cap B] = P[A]P[B]$ prove $P[A^c \cap B^c] = P[A^c]P[B^c]$ without using independence using the fact that $(A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A \cup B) = S$

I have tried to rearrange equation but I never get anywhere, replacing $A$ with $1-A^c$ and $B$ with $1-B^c$ seems to go nowhere, nor does $P[(A^c \cap B^c)] + P[(A \cup B)] = 1$

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint given, we have $\mathbb{P}(A^c\cap B^c)=1-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$. Moreover,
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$
hence
$$ \mathbb{P}(A^c\cap B^c)=1-[\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)]=1-\mathbb{P}(A)-\mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) $$
$$ =(1-\mathbb{P}(A))(1-\mathbb{P}(B))=\mathbb{P}(A^c)\mathbb{P}(B^c) $$

Comment: Damn, I feel like a noob for not seeing that.  Had 10 mins on a quiz to do it too, it just seems to unintuitive!

Comment: It can be a bit tricky to find the right order in which to apply all the rules, especially under time pressure.